# Laravel API returns Invalid JSON

Tags: json, laravel, rest, character-encoding, content-encoding

In `routes/api.php` I have created following route

```
Route::get('/config', function(){
    return response()->json([
        'cdn' => cdn_url(),
        'slide_image_path' => '/uploads/front-slides/',
        'offer_image_path' => '/uploads/offers/',
        'offer_image_thumb_path' => '/uploads/offers/thumbs/'
    ]);
});
```

In browser, I am doing

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'https://www.example.com/api/config',
    success : function(response){
        var data = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

and getting an error "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1";
But when I use core php's `json_encode()` the json response is getting parsed successfully.

Also when I use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to validate JSON
It can parse JSON without any issue no matter what I use (`json_encode()` or `response()->json()`). But it also gives a warning about invalid JSON.

So far, I have observed that when I use `json_encode()`, the response contains a header "Content Encoding: gzip".
But when I use Laravel's `response()->json()`, The header Content Encoding: gzip is absent.

I have also tried setting this header manually with `header('Content-Encoding: gzip')` function while using `response()->json()`. But then browser gives error "net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED";

I think its an issue related to content encoding or character encoding.

Comment: you don't need to parse it, use it as it is

Answer (score 1):

It doens't seem to be anything wrong in your response. The problem is when you are receiving/parsing the data.

Try to use the `stringify` method:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'https://www.example.com/api/config',
    success : function(response){
        var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```